# Reshape spark data frame of key-value pairs with keys as new columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark and scala. Lets say I have a data frame of lists that are key value pairs. Is there a way to map the id vars of column ids as new columns?

```
df.show()
+--------------------+--------------------  +
| ids                | vals                 |
+--------------------+--------------------  +
|[id1,id2,id3]       | null                 |
|[id2,id5,id6]       |[WrappedArray(0,2,4)] |
|[id2,id4,id7]       |[WrappedArray(6,8,10)]|
```

Expected output:

```
+----+----+
|id1 | id2| ...
+----+----+
|null| 0  | ...
|null| 6  | ...
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible way would be to compute the columns of the new DataFrame and use those columns to construct the rows.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val data = List((Seq("id1","id2","id3"),None),(Seq("id2","id4","id5"),Some(Seq(2,4,5))),(Seq("id3","id5","id6"),Some(Seq(3,5,6))))

val df = sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF("ids","values")

val values = df.flatMap{
  case Row(t1:Seq[String], t2:Seq[Int]) => Some((t1 zip t2).toMap)
  case Row(_, null) => None
}

// get the unique names of the columns across the original data
val ids = df.select(explode($"ids")).distinct.collect.map(_.getString(0))

// map the values to the new columns (to Some value or None)
val transposed = values.map(entry => Row.fromSeq(ids.map(id => entry.get(id))))

// programmatically recreate the target schema with the columns we found in the data
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = StructType(ids.map(id => StructField(id, IntegerType, nullable=true)))

// Create the new DataFrame
val transposedDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(transposed, schema)
```

This process will pass through the data 2 times, although depending on the backing data source, calculating the column names can be rather cheap.

Also, this goes back and forth between `DataFrames` and `RDD`. I would be interested in seeing a "pure" DataFrame process.

Comment: Thanks! I manage to simplify my problem and solving it in an easier way without the need of the general solution (filtering the data rendered me a DF with the same ids on all rows).

Comment: In the end I ended up needing your solution. However, I get, `warning: non-variable type argument String in type pattern Seq[String] (the underlying of Seq[String]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure` running yours example stright of.

Comment: @johnblund That's a JVM limitation due to type erasure. To avoid the warning, one would have to cast the objects (t1, t2 above) to their types at runtime. But declaring the types here, helps the compiler validate the code statically and we know it's correct.